# Facebook registerCallbackManager giving error (Facebook sign in with Firebase)

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is the error that is showing the logcat :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent { (has
>   extras) }} to activity
>   {com.fmstudios.Aprende_Ingles_Desde0/com.fmstudios.Aprende_Ingles_Desde0.LoginActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String java.lang.Throwable.toString()' on a null object
>   reference

I have my `OnCreate` like this :

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_button2);

    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email","public_profile");


    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d("vfd", "cancela");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            Log.v("LoginActivity", exception.getCause().toString());
        }
    });

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {

        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

Also, I have to say that `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());` didn't solved my problem

Comment: You’ll need to be more explicit than this. Also while you’re at it, since you are writing Java, I suggest you rename your package to the usual conventions:  (Package names are written in all lower case to avoid conflict with the names of classes or interfaces), Source:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Comment: Im trying to use the facebook sign in and that's what's happening after trying to use it, I don't how to be more specific than this, I'm sorry. Thank you for told me about the way that packages are written, I didn't knew it :)